# Understanding static and dynamic with vue.js

Tags: vue.js, dynamic, static

I'm currently wondering about the difference between static and dynamic pages when using vue.js.

Are vue.js pages static or dynamic?
They can change on user interactions but not necessarily need to interact with the server to change data, when not using axios or alike. So does it still count as static just changing the frontend itself on input or interactions?

Little confused about this. Hope for good explanations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A **static page** is a page delivered to the user exactly as stored and with no chance on being changed, end of story!

Although **dynamic pages** can take 2 types: **Client-side dynamic web page** and a **Server-side dynamic web page**.

***Client-side dynamic page*** is changed without server requests. For example, when you click a button and something pops on the screen, or some content on the page changes, etc... (i think you take the idea).

***Server-side dynamic page*** is changed with server requests, as you said for example, with HTTP requests using Axios.

And this is not the Vue.js definition, is the default definition for static and dynamic pages.